# Reorder ul li with image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to reorder my images. But its not working. I'm trying same this with text its working. But what happened with images. Images are not reordered. Any suggestions please.

```js
 $(function() {
    $( ".sortable-row" ).sortable({
 //alert("a");
 });
  });
```

```css
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
 }
 li {
    display: inline;
 }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable-row" >
<li id="1" class="status"><img id="1" width="220px" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ijex5274t_c/hqdefault.jpg"/></li>
<li id="2" class="status"><img id="2" width="220px" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/dDAP9OWtQro/hqdefault.jpg"/></li>
<li id="3" class="status"><img id="3" width="220px" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/hajnEpCq5SE/hqdefault.jpg"/></li>
<li id="4" class="status"><img id="4" width="220px" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/jyTA33HQZLA/hqdefault.jpg"/></li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable-row" >
<li id="15" class="status">Link one</li>
<li id="16" class="status">Link two</li>
<li id="17" class="status">Link three</li>
<li id="18" class="status">Link four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change CSS of <li> element to match its height with images.

Use:

```
li {display:inline-block}
```